# Android Paho. How to send messages on network enabled

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I am use Android MQTT Paho client to send messages with QoS 2.
How to save messages if network on device disabled and send when network enabled?

```
mClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this, uri, clientId, new   MqttDefaultFilePersistence());
MqttConnectOptions conOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();

conOpt.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
conOpt.setCleanSession(true);
conOpt.setAutomaticReconnect(true);

mClient.setTraceEnabled(true);

mClient.setCallback(this);
mClient.setTraceCallback(this);

IMqttToken connectToken = mClient.connect(conOpt, null, this);
```

And offline buffering options:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
    this.disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
    this.disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);

    mClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);

    subscribe(topic);
}
```

Messages published to topic if the network is available, but if it disabled and enabled again offline messages not sending.

Comment: Show us the code, what have you already tried?

Comment: @hardillb i am added code sample

Comment: I think you can RETAIN your sent messages & take further process. That might be the currently available solution to your problem. Reference link : http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-enyclopedia-paho-android-service

Comment: Retain is flag for server and it not working on client side.